# Data loss when draining Dataflow job that reads from PubSub and writes to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When putting a fixed number of strings (800,000 1KB used to test) into a PubSub topic and running the following Apache Beam (2.1.0) job in Dataflow, exactly once semantics are preserved as expected.

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.FixedWindows;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

public class PubSubToGsSimpleJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PubSubToGsPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(PubSubToGsPipelineOptions.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.getInput()))
                .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
                .apply(TextIO.write().withWindowedWrites().withNumShards(1).to(options.getOutput()));
        p.run();
    }

}
```

`PipelineOptions` implementation below

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;

public interface PubSubToGsPipelineOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("PubSub subscription")
    String getInput();
    void setInput(String input);

    @Description("Google Cloud Storage output path")
    String getOutput();
    void setOutput(String output);
}
```

However, if the same job is run, drained before all the elements are read (as shown in the Dataflow console), and kicked off again, the output files have fewer records than the original data set that was published in to the PubSub topic. This is suggesting that draining and replacing a job can cause data loss which seems odd since [this google cloud blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/managing-streaming-pipelines-in-google-cloud-dataflow-just-got-better) mentions that `Drain and replace` should have at least once semantics. How should this pipeline be designed to achieve at least once semantics (or better yet exactly once semantics) when draining and replacing the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that a window might be partially written before drain and replacement job overwrites it with the remaining window. You can check the worker logs from drained job and replacement job for this log line [in WriteFiles](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.1.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/WriteFiles.java#L321). If you use Beam HEAD it also logs when it the final destination is overwritten.

Conceptually drained job and replacement jobs are entirely different pipelines. Using same output location is not different from using same output location for two other unrelated jobs. Another thing you could try is to use different output path for second job and verify that all the records exist across both directories.

Comment: That said, may be TextIO can/should handle such a case better (if above guess is correct). Please confirm if changing output path preserves all the records. That would confirm Dataflow's guarantees.

Comment: I could not find a line matching the log pattern. Configuring the replacement job to write to a separate output produce at least once semantics. There were some duplicate records meaning exactly once semantics were not maintained using PubSub as a source.


The blog post also mentions  `If your custom source guarantees exactly-once delivery and provides source-side buffering, Drain and replace can provide exactly-once semantics.` Since PubSub messages can be buffered before responding with an ACK, does this suggest PubSub can provide exactly once semantics?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the work around. I will file a bug for TextIO. I am surprised you are seeing duplicates. PubSub should provide exactly-once semantics in this case. It will be very useful if you could provide some more information (and job_id id you can). I certainly interested in digging more into source of duplicates.

Comment: I published 400,000 1 KB messages to a topic twice for a total of 800,000 messages. The first job_id is `2017-11-20_13_28_21-10176415107474168935` and the second job_id is `2017-11-20_13_33_36-16877393480404727048`. According to the Dataflow console, the first job consumed 792,139 elements and the second job consumed 40,155 elements. Comparing the two job outputs to the original messages I can confirm that 32,294 messages were found 3 times instead of the expected 2 times. This value is equal to `sum_of_elements - original_message_count = (792,139 + 40,155) - 800,000 = 32,294`

Comment: I am looking into it.You mentioned '3 times instead of expected 2 times'. Did you mean '2 times instead of once'? Otherwise could you elaborate bit more on what you mean by duplicates?
EDIT: never mind.. you mentioned each message exists twice in your input.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. What you are seeing with duplicates is possible. When you drain pipeline waits for processing to finish, but does not wait for acks back to PubSub to complete. Agreed that pipeline could wait for the acks to be flushed, it will certainly make such duplicates across drain much less frequent. But note that it can not guarantee exactly-once since there is no guarantee that PubSub does not lose an ack and serve the message again. In a normal pipeline such duplicates are removed (state stored includes relevant info). But there is no state available across drain.